# One-form symmetry action in 4d Maxwell - closed or not?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

**Note:** I had an overlong post which I was advised to break into pieces - here is my first, most basic question. Next question is [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/739096/).

I'm trying to understand how the electric one-form symmetry acts in 4d Maxwell theory on a manifold without boundary, and then what it means to try to gauge it. SE answers I've already read include [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/495051/210239), [3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/391638/210239), [4](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/532008/210239) and [5](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/237557/210239), but I wasn't able to get a complete picture.

***What is the precise action of the global one-form symmetry on the operators, vs a possibly gauged version?***

Here is my current understanding.

The Maxwell action is

$$
S_0 = \int \frac{1}{2g^2} F\wedge \star F
$$
with $F = dA$ (locally).

We can see that this action is totally invariant under $A \rightarrow A + \lambda$, if $d \lambda = 0$. $\lambda = d\omega$ is of course the 0-form gauge symmetry.

While $S_0$ is invariant, the shift in $A$ will be detected by Wilson lines
$$
W_n[C] = e^{i n \oint A} \rightarrow e^{in \oint \lambda} W_n[C].
$$

[This SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/495051/210239) shows that the phase picked up is topological in the sense that it depends only on the homology class of $C$, since if $C \sqcup (-C') = \partial \Sigma$ then
$$
\int_C \lambda - \int_{C'} \lambda  = \int_{\Sigma} d\lambda = 0.
$$
Just as global 0-form symmetries involve shifting a field by a constant, i.e a 0-dimensional operator which doesn't change when you move around the connected manifold, so does a 1-form global symmetry involve shifting a field by a 1-dimensional operator that doesn't depend on how you smoothly deform it. Crucially this requires $d\lambda=0$.

On the other hand, consider shifting by some $\lambda$ such that $d\lambda \neq 0$. Then
$$
\Delta S_0 = \frac{1}{g^2} \int \star F \wedge d \lambda = \frac{1}{g^2} \int d\star F \wedge \lambda = 0 
$$
by virtue of the equation of motion for $A$. (This is up to some $d\lambda \wedge \star d\lambda$ term we are allowed to absorb.).

[Elsewhere](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.15401) $\lambda$ is referred to as a *flat* connection, but a field is still said to shift by $d\lambda$.

$\color{orange}{\textbf{THE QUESTION}}$

Does the global symmetry action have $d\lambda = 0$ (as is held to be the case in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/532008/210239)) or not? If not, what equations does $\lambda$ have to obey, and what changes about these equations when we consider trying to gauge the symmetry?

Compare this to the 0-form case where we start with a shift by a constant $\alpha$, then, when we gauge, consider the more general $\alpha(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is essentially what @ACuriousMind pointed out in a comment (which I will quote here, because [comments are intended to be temporary](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment))

> if you use the equations of motion you're **not** demonstrating a symmetry. $δS=0$ under all possible infinitesimal variations is the *definition of a solution of the equations of motion*, so if you have to use the equation of motions to arrive at $δS=0$, you're not showing anything interesting - symmetries have to be off-shell, see also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/614484/50583).

Another way to see this, which is inherently a QFT statement is through the path integral. $\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\D}{\mathrm{D}}$Namely, the gauge fields are dummy integration variables, i.e.
$$\int\D a \exp(-S[a]) = \int\D a' \exp(-S[a']).\tag{1}$$

But now, take $S[a]$ to be the Maxwell action<sup>$1$</sup>
$$S[a]=\frac{1}{2g^2}\Vert f\Vert^2,$$
and take $a' = a+\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is allowed to have some curvature.  You can most easily see that $\D a' = \D a$ and
$$S[a'] = \frac{1}{2g^2}\left(\Vert f\Vert^2 + 2\left<f,\d \lambda\right> + \Vert\d \lambda\Vert^2\right)$$
Then (1) says that
$$\int\D a \exp(-S[a]) = \int\D a \exp\!\left(-S[a]+\frac{1}{g^2}\left<f,\d \lambda\right> + \frac{1}{2g^2}\Vert\d \lambda\Vert^2\right),$$
which is true *if and only if* $\d\lambda = 0$.

Therefore only shifts by flat connections give a symmetry of Maxwell theory.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> where $\Vert\bullet\Vert^2$ comes from the usual inner-product $\left<\bullet,\circ\right>:=\int \bullet\wedge\star\circ$</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this response, that's very clear. Followup questions are
1. If we gauge the symmetry, are we considering non-flat $\lambda$?
2. Are there subtleties involved in the fact that the one-form electric current is only conserved when $A$ is on-shell?

Comment: @quixot for 1. I believe that's one of the main topics in your other question, which I'll answer when/if I have the time, unless someone else answers it sufficiently before I manage to do so. Short answer is yes. I don't understand what you mean by 2. Do you mean when $\lambda$ is not flat? This just tells you that there isn't a global symmetry for non-flat $\lambda$.

Comment: I just mean that $dJ_e=d\star F = 0$ is the equation of motion for $A$.

Comment: Would it be fair to say the following: symmetries must have $\delta S = 0$ off-shell, but their associated current is only conserved on-shell?

Comment: @quixot, yes, that is correct

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!