# 4d Maxwell one-form symmetry: freedom to add 'local terms'

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

**Note:** I have a related question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/739076/). I was advised to split my questions into a series of posts.

I am trying to understand the mixed 't Hooft anomaly between the electric and magnetic one-form symmetries in 4d Maxwell. SE answers I've already read include [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/495051/210239), [3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/391638/210239), [4](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/532008/210239) and [5](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/237557/210239), but I wasn't able to get a complete picture.

In this post I will ask about what happens when we start trying to gauge the electric one-form symmetry in 4d Maxwell on a manifold without boundary - i.e. for now I will neglect the magnetic symmetry.

To review: the Maxwell action
$$
S_0 = \int \frac{1}{2g^2} F\wedge \star F
$$
has a conserved current
$$
J_e = \frac{2}{g^2} \star F \; \; (\text{from the equation of motion for } A).
$$

Now we set about trying to gauge the electric symmetry. This involves introducing a background field $B_e$ coupled to the current $J_e$. The minimal coupling is
$$
S_e = \int \frac{1}{2g^2} F\wedge \star F - \frac{2}{g^2} \star F \wedge B_e
$$

---

*This changes the equation of motion to $d\star F = 2 d \star B$, which usually signals an anomaly. But I believe there should be no anomaly at this stage.*

---

We can [apparently](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.15401) express the action as
$$
S_e' = \int \frac{1}{2g^2} (F -  B_e)\wedge \star (F -  B_e) 
$$

---

*Why are we allowed to do this? I get*
$$
S_e' = S_e + \int \frac{1}{2g^2} B_e \wedge \star B_e + \frac{1}{g^2} \star F \wedge B_e,
$$
*[This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/391638/210239) says we are 'allowed to add local terms' quadratic in the background field, like $B\wedge \star B$ - why?*

*If we do gauge it, the term is no longer a background term. Why are we still allowed to equate the two expressions?*

*There's also an extra $\star F \wedge B_e$ because of a relative factor of $4$ between the original terms. What do we do with this? Why did we even define the current with that particular coefficient?*